# How do i get this function equivalent in MongoDB, faster? WHERE clause?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, performance, collections

i want to know how to query like MYSQL in java this function equivalent: `SELECT nick FROM profiles WHERE uuid = 'something';`

i have done something like that in my project but it seens too slow and its returning the whole document of the profile requested, unless i use document.get("nick") i get exactly what i want, i'm sorry but i'm really new to MongoDB and i haven't already founded something about this, everything that i found it doesn't really helped me so much..

this is the code:

```
FindIterable<Document> results = Main.getCollection(Main.getDatabase(plugin.database), plugin.collection).find(Document.parse("{ uid: '00000000-0000-0000-0009-01fbbfda08e8' }, { nick: 1 }")); 
           Document document = results.first();
           if(document.get("nick") != player.getName()) {
               System.out.println("do something");
           }
```

by document var from FindIterable it returns the whole document, but i just want to return the nick of that profile, which the uuid is "00000000-0000-0000-0009-01fbbfda08e8" so i dont need to use document.get and it will be much better for performance, if thats possible.. (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at how indexes and covered queries work (projections), creating an index for a specific fields would improve your performance for those common queries, and projections would help you to get only the fields you need.

There are plenty of examples (in java also)
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#covered-queries

Here there is an example of exactly what you are asking for:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Field projection applied on your example:

```
.find(eq("uid", "00000000-0000-0000-0009-01fbbfda08e8")).projection(fields(include("nick"), excludeId()));
```

Comment: As you can see i've been using already this same documentation as basement when Document.parse but it seens not working for me, everytime i try to use these example it returns the whole document for me, being i just want a value of a key in a especific document requested, (if that makes sense) i am using something like that as basement: http://prntscr.com/sl0450

Comment: @LeonardoS.J. I just edited my answer with the code

Comment: I have a question regarding this code, sorry to return to the topic, I just wanted to ask if this function takes only the nick part of the database, just like MySQL or it just has the procedure of executing the entire document and then shorten it to just the nick for the output (exit) to be nick and value? I would like to just receive the nick and the value, without the server having to read the entire document, just like MySQL does with databases.

Comment: Again i forward you to that link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/. First paragrph: "By default, queries in MongoDB return all fields in matching documents. To limit the amount of data that MongoDB sends to applications, you can include a projection document to specify or restrict fields to return."